# Drag and drop shapes and colors jquery

Tags: jquery, html, colors, drag-and-drop, shapes

I have problem with triangle shape, when I drag & drop triangle it doesn't change color properly and with other shapes it works well. I can't find what is problem with triangl shape.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="figur.css">
      <title>Spel för barn</title>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#rektangel" ).draggable();
            $( "#fyrkant" ).draggable();

            $( "#rektangelbox" ).droppable({
               accept: "#rektangel",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Bra!" );
               }
            });

            $( "#fyrkantbox" ).droppable({
               accept: "#fyrkant",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Bra!" );
               }
            });

            $( "#cirkel" ).draggable({scope : "cirkel"});
            $( "#triangel" ).draggable({scope : "triangel"});

            $( "#cirkelbox" ).droppable({
               scope: "cirkel",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Bra!" );
               }
            });

            $( "#triangelbox" ).droppable({
               scope: "triangel",
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this )
                  .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                  .find( "p" )
                  .html( "Bra!" );
               }
            }); 
         });
      </script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#triangel, #fyrkant, #cirkel, #rektangel").draggable();
        $("#triangelbox, #fyrkantbox, #cirkelbox, #rektangelbox").droppable({
            greedy: true,
            drop: function()
            {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#07f507"); 
                $(this).html("Bra!")
            },
            tolerance: "pointer",
            hoverClass: "dark"
        });
    });
    </script>

      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#triangel").draggable();
        $("#triangelbox").droppable({
            greedy: true,
            drop: function()
            {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#07f507"); 
                $(this).html("Bra!")
            },
            tolerance: "pointer",
            hoverClass: "dark"
        });
    });
    </script>

      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#fyrkant, #cirkel, #rektangel, #triangel" ).draggable({ revert: "valid" });
        $( "#fyrkant, #cirkel, #rektangel, #triangel" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

        $( "" ).droppable({
          classes: {
            "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-active",
            "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
          },
          drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
              .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
              .find( "p" )
                .html( "" );
          }
        });
      } );
      </script>
      <script>
        $( "li" ).hover(
          function() {
            $( this ).append( $( "<span> ***</span>" ) );
          }, function() {
            $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
          }
        );

        $( "li.fade" ).hover(function() {
          $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
          $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
        });
</script>

      <button onclick="myFunction()"><b>Starta om spelet här!</b></button>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            location.reload();
        }
        </script>

   <body>
        <center>
            <div class = "containerpratbubbla">
                    <div class="bubble">
                      Hej där! <br> Vill du lära dig geometriska figurer? Då har du kommit till rätt plats! Här får du nämligen lära dig hur olika figurer ser ut, och du kommer också få chansen att spela ett spel! 
                    </div>

                    <div class="bubble1">
                      Hej där! <br> Jag ska lära dig hur spelet går till! Du ska dra de små svarta figurerna till de större vita, och para ihop rätt figur, till exempel triangel med triangel. Svårare än så är det inte! Lycka till!
                    </div>
                <br><br>
            </div>
        </center>

            <img src = "http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Cartoon-PNG-HD.png" style = "display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
            <br><br>

        <center>
          <div class = "container1">

             <div id = "rektangel" class = "ui-widget-content">
                <p></p>
             </div>

             <div id = "fyrkant" class = "ui-widget-content">
                <p></p>
             </div>

             <div id = "cirkel" class = "ui-widget-content">
                <p></p>
             </div>

             <div id = "triangel" class = "ui-widget-content">
                <p></p>
             </div>

           </div>
        </center>

      </div>
      <br><br><br>
        <center> 
              <div class = "container" >

                <div id="rektangelbox" class = "ui-widget-header">
                    <p></p>
                </div>

                <div id="fyrkantbox" class = "ui-widget-header">
                <p></p>
                </div>

                 <div id="cirkelbox" class = "ui-widget-header">
                    <p></p>
                 </div>

                 <div id="triangelbox" class = "ui-widget-header">
                    <div class="text_inside">
                        <p>Bra!</p>
                    </div>
                 </div>

              </div>
        </center>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
    </center>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #ffa600;
}

.container, .containerpratbubbla {
    display: table-row-group;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.containerpratbubbla {
    margin: 0 auto
}

.container1 {
    display: table-row-group;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#cirkel {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em; 
}

#cirkelbox {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em; 
    background-color: white;
}

#triangel {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 3em solid transparent;
    border-right: 3em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 4.8em solid black;
    float: left;
}

#triangelbox {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10em solid transparent;
    border-right: 10em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 14em solid white;
    float: left;
}

.text_inside {
    padding-top: 1em;
    margin-left: -0.7em
}

#rektangel {
    width: 150px; 
    height: 50px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 0; 
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

#fyrkant {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 0; 
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

#fyrkantbox { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px;  
    background-color: white;
}

#rektangelbox { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em; 
    float: left; 
    margin: 10px;  
    background-color: white;
}

.bubble 
    {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: black solid 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 10px
    }

.bubble:after 
    {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 70%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1; 
    }

.bubble:before 
    {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -19.5px;
    left: calc(70% - 3px) ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 18px 0;
    border-color: black transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    }

.bubble1 
    {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-height: 2em;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: black solid 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    }

.bubble1:after 
    {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 20%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }

.bubble1:before 
    {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -19.5px;
    left: calc(20% - 3px) ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 18px 18px 0;
    border-color: black transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    }

. dark {
    background-color: red !important;   
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 695px){
    img { width: 500px; height: 500px}
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 550px){
    img { width: 330px; height: 330px}
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    #fyrkantbox { width: 150px; height: 150px }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    #rektangelbox { width: 250px; height: 150px; }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    #triangelbox { border-left: 6.5em solid transparent; 
                   border-right: 6.5em solid transparent;   
                   border-bottom: 11em solid white; }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    #cirkelbox { width: 150px; height: 150px }



 @media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #fyrkantbox { width: 100px; height: 100px }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #rektangelbox { width: 200px; height: 100px; }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #triangelbox { border-left: 5em solid transparent; 
                   border-right: 5em solid transparent;     
                   border-bottom: 7.8em solid white; }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
    #cirkelbox { width: 100px; height: 100px }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 730px){
    #fyrkantbox, #cirkelbox, #rektangelbox, #triangelbox { margin: 4.3%;}
```

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO forums. Please, next time try to put just the code related to your specific problem. If you paste your whole code it will be difficult to read and therefore very tricky to find the problem.

The problem of your code is due to the way that you have applied the color in the triangle. All your shapes are regular `divs` with a background color, except the triangle, this last one has been formed using borders with colors. So, you need to change your code to use `border-color` with the triangle:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
   $("#triangel").draggable();
   $("#triangelbox").droppable({
       greedy: true,
       drop: function()
       {
           //---Use a border color instead a background color
           $(this).css("border-bottom-color", "#07f507"); 
           $(this).html("Bra!")
       },
       tolerance: "pointer",
       hoverClass: "dark"
   });
});
```